# Lista duplamente ligada e circular, erros de memória com o valgrind

Tags: c, lista-encadeada, valgrind

Eu tenho as seguintes estruturas:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    char info[40];
    struct Node *ant;
    struct Node *prox;
}NoCDup;

typedef struct LDEC
{
    NoCDup *cabeca;
    NoCDup *cauda;
    int tamanho;
}ListaCDup;
```

E também a função que inicializa a lista duplamente ligada e circular:

```
ListaCDup *criar()
{
    ListaCDup *p = (ListaCDup*) malloc (sizeof(ListaCDup));
    p->cabeca = p->cauda = NULL;
    p->tamanho = 0;
    return p;
}
```

E na main simplesmente:

```
int main(){

    ListaCDup *l = criar();


    ImprimeListaCDup(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Porém ao verificar erros de memória com o valgrind, eu tenho o seguinte problema:

```
==10879==     in use at exit: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==10879==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 12 bytes allocated
==10879== 
==10879== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==10879==    at 0x482E27C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==10879==    by 0x10869E: criar (in /home/student/Downloads/lista)
==10879==    by 0x108D3B: main (in /home/student/Downloads/lista)
```

Alguém sabe me explicar o por quê?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você faz a alocação de uma nova lista utilizando `malloc` mas não tem o `free` correspondente para liberar essa memória alocada. Isso é visivel na informação dada pelo *valgrind*

> total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 12 bytes allocated

Repare que tem 1 alloc e 0 free, e até consegue ver que na sua maquina o espaço utilizado pela estrutura é de 12 bytes.

Assumindo que vai precisar da lista durante o decorrer de todo o programa, pode libera-la no fim, antes do `main` terminar:

```
int main(){
    ListaCDup *l = criar();

    ImprimeListaCDup(l);
    free(l); //<-- liberar a lista alocada anteriormente
    return 0;
}
```

Se antes do fim já não precisar desta lista deve libera-la de imediato. A liberação deve ser feita o mais cedo possível, a partir do ponto em que não necessita dela.